# In xcode for iOS how can I compare a textfield to two strings?

Tags: ios, xcode, string, if-statement

The question might seem a bit confusing but I have an if statement that looks something like this

```
if ([textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"Fish"])

{
    wrong.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    wrong.text = @"Correct";
        } else {
            wrong.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            wrong.text = @"Wrong, try again";
                }
```

Is there an easy way to have it equal to two strings, i.e. it will be correct if they enter Fish or Chips in the textAnswer field?

I have tried entering it like this

```
   ([textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"Fish",@"Chip"])
```

but Xcode flags up an error saying only one statement not two.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be two comparisons and the combined sense of their results: `if ([textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"Fish"] || [textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"Chips"])`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also check if the string is in an array:

```
NSArray *goodStrings;
NSUInteger index;

goodStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
               @"Fish", @"Chips", "Beer", nil];

index = [goodStrings textAnswer.text];
if(index == NSNotFound) {
    // not found
} else {
    // found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code Phillip postet is correct. But if you have more than 2 or 3 strings you want to compare, you could put them all in an NSArray and do this:

```
NSArray *yourArray = [@"Word1 Word2 Word3" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *yourString = @"Fish";

if([yourArray containsObject:yourString]){
 /* Do Something */
}
```